# Reduce Logs of Custom App

Tags: configuration, app, logging

We've written an app for SP 2013 that reloads pictures from a library permanently to show a kind of slide show. All for good and this is running well but now we've detected that the app writes loads of log entries. Every timer tick the app logs

```
Monitoring nasq Medium: Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://.... 
Logging Correlation Data xmnv Medium: Name=Request (GET:http:...
Monitoring b4ly Medium: Leaving monitored scope (Request (GET:http://....
```

and so on and on. This creates logs up to 0.5 GB which exceeds the flood line.

So what can we do? The diagnostic logging is already at minimum config.
Can we somehow avoid these traces?

Comment: Very good question. I have the same problem. Have you tried backing up the databases. It helps somehow.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint automatically creates a new ULS log file every 30 minutes to limit the size of each file.

One of the first configurations made in a new production server farm is to move these files to another hard drive on each server within the farm. The C-drive is critical to running the OS.

The ULS can and should be configured to prevent unnecessary data from filling up disk space. You can access these settings using Central Administration (CA) under Monitoring | Configure Diagnostic Logging.

You can set how many days of log files should be kept on each server. The default is 14 days. ULS files older than that number of days will be automatically removed from the system. If you need to log large amounts of data or maintain an indefinite history of log files, it may be preferable to back up and remove these files every 30 minutes when each file is closed and the next file is created.

You can also configure a maximum amount of disk space. When this limit is reached, the oldest log files are automatically removed to free up space.

Refer [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn383981.aspx) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid this ,SharePoint 2010 is equipped with a set of new tools to improve the monitoring of your custom applications, there are built-in functionality to check how long your operations take. All this is logged and can be visualized in the Developer Dashboard.

Everything is executed under a Monitored Scope. Each scope has a set of Monitors that measures and counts calls and timings. If you notice the log files it says when it is entering the specific monitored scope and when it leaves it, it keeps track of the time taken etc.